# Why does it show me that the "Route [searchbybrand] not defined." in a laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Im working on a e-commerce web-app using laravel. I have a section called shop by brand with the pictures of the brands and when i click on the picture i want it to show me the products of that brand.

This is the blade part of my code where i call the route:

```
                <div class="brand-slides owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="brand-item">
                        <a href="{{route('searchbybrand')}}"><img src="assets/img/brand/shopbybrand1.jpg" alt="image"></a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
    public function  searchVendor()
    {
        $searchproduct="Fanola";

        $product=product::Where('vendor','LIKE',"%$searchproduct%")->get();

        return view('home.userpage',compact('product'));
    }
```

At the moment its just a simple code that will work with the "Fanola" brand only. I did it this way just to test if it works.

And this is my route in my web.php:

```
Route::get('/searchbybrand', [HomeController::class, 'searchVendor']);
```

The error it shows me when i serve it is "Route [searchbybrand] not defined."

Ive tried clearing the route cache and it still doesnt work. I asked chat gpt about this and it gave me different ideas like defining the route like this:

```
Route::get('search-by-brand', 'HomeController@searchVendor')->name('searchbybrand');
```

When i do it like this it shows a different error: "Target class [HomeController] does not exist."

I also tried composer dump-autoload, php artisan config:clear and php artisan cache:clear as per its suggestions but none of them worked.

Comment: You need to add a name to the route. In the first one definition you havent.

Answer (score 1):

this is because your route doesn't have a name you can fix it like this

```
Route::get('/searchbybrand', [HomeController::class, 'searchVendor'])->name('searchbybrand');
```

or instead of that in your blade you can use `url` instead of `route`

```
                <div class="brand-slides owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="brand-item">
                        <a href="{{url('searchbybrand')}}"><img src="assets/img/brand/shopbybrand1.jpg" alt="image"></a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
```

and for your second problem which says `Target class [HomeController] does not exist.` add this in top of your web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
```

also at the end run

```
php artisan optimize
```